# Something more beautiful than <__main__.MyClass instance at 0x1624710>

Tags: python, class

This is my class (as simple as it can be):

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

    def __str__(self):
        return "MyClass #%d" % self.id
```

When I print an object of MyClass, I get this beautiful string: `MyClass #id`. But when I just "show it" in the interpreter, I still get this nasty `<__main__...>`. Is there a way to change this behaviour?

```
>>> c = MyClass(5)
>>> print c
MyClass #5
>>> c
<__main__.MyClass instance at 0x1624710>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'MyClass #%d' % (self.id,)
```

Comment: The reason why this works is that `>>> c` is really like `>>> print repr(c)`, i.e., it prints a Python representation of `c` (which usually contains more information than `str(c)`, as it is ideally a full representation of the object).

Comment: This has to be the fastest and more useful answer I've ever received

Comment: If you want `str` and `repr` to give you the same string, you can use `__repr__ = __str__` as a shortcut (or vice versa, but obviously not both!)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> class MyClass():
...     def __init__(self, id):
...         self.id = id
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "MyClass #%d" % self.id
... 
>>> c = MyClass(5)
>>> c
MyClass #5
```