# Python - instance at 0x028A1828

Tags: python, pointers, memory-address

I am implementing a linked list and when I try to print the value that a node points to I get its memory address in the console. Is there any way to convert this to the value associated with it?

```
print "[Data: " + `data` + " | Next: " + `temp.next` + " ]"
```

**Output:**

[Data: 1 | Next: None]

[Data: 2 | Next: cell.Cell instance at 0x028A1828 ]

Comment: don't use backticks to convert an object to a string, use string formatting instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8349054/3001761

Answer (score 4):

You can override `__repr__` appropriately:

```
class Node:
    …

    def __repr__(self):
        return "[Data: {!r} | Next: {!r}]".format(self.data, self.next)
```

Then you’ll also be able to just call `print(node)` to get a useful representation of the node. (This assumes your node is a class.)

Answer (score 2):

Your cell class needs a `__str__`-method, to convert itself into a string.

```
class Cell(object):
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return "your cell as a string"
```