# Why do I get two strings when I execute ChristmassTree(), but one when I execute ct = ChristmassTree()

Tags: python-2.7

I have just recently started studying object oriented **Python**, so I have this question.

Firstly, I have created these classes:

```
class Tree:
count = 0

def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    Tree.count += 1

def displayTree(self):
    print "Total amount of Trees: %d"% Tree.count

class ChristmasTree(Tree):
    def __init__(self):
        Tree.count += 1
        print "I am a ChristmasTree. I am the most beautiful among %d"% Tree.count + " trees"
```

So, I don't understand why do I see the two strings when I execute this command:

```
ChristmasTree()
```

output:

```
I am a ChristmasTree. I am the most beautiful among {variable} trees
<Tree.ChristmasTree instance at 0x00000000002209788>
```

but I get one line when I execute this command:

```
ct = ChristmasTree()
```

output:

```
I am a ChristmasTree. I am the most beautiful among {variable} trees
```

According to my logic there should be one line of output like this:

```
I am a ChristmasTree. I am the most beautiful among {variable} trees
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a function without assigning a name to the output, the output will be "shown", i.e. its `__repr__(self)` method will be called. The default is to return the instance's address in memory, [but you can overwrite it with a `__repr__` method of your own.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349054/something-more-beautiful-than-main-myclass-instance-at-0x1624710)

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you are trying to do here. But at least, you need to call `Tree.__init__(name,age)` in your `ChristmasTree`'s `__init__` method.

Comment: Thank you, that's just for studying purposes.
I am editting the code and trying to understand the output.